# How do I get the name of the Salesforce lightning app a user is running via Apex?

Tags: apex

Say the user is running an App called Sales. How do I get that information via Apex?

My use case is that I have a Visual Force redirect. It calls a method on initialization that returns a page reference. This is great except that I'd like to use the same page redirect code within multiple apps and have it send a different redirection link depending on the App.

For example I could have my code determine the name of the App (i.e. Sales) and then look for a Custom Meta Data record with the name matching the App and look for a URL field on that record to feed back as part of the page reference that is returned.

Where I am stuck is figuring out how to get the App I am in so I can then do something dynamic based on that.

Comment: Why do you need this information in `Apex`? It seems like something you could pass to your controller as a parameter to some method call, but it is hard to give good advice when your question contains so little detail.

Comment: @AdrianLarson  I added some additional context to my question.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the app's name by using its TabSetDescribe.  Something like this should work:

```
// Get the tabset describes for all apps
List<Schema.DescribeTabSetResult> tabSetDesc = Schema.describeTabs();

String currentAppName;

// Loop through the tabset describes until we get to the current app's tabset
for(Schema.DescribeTabSetResult tsr : tabSetDesc){
    if(tsr.isSelected()){
        currentAppName = tsr.getLabel();
        break;
    }

}
return currentAppName;
```

Comment: Whoa, this is something I never even knew about. Kudos.

Comment: @Joseph, did this work for you? Curious about the end result!

Comment: This won't work for lightning apps as Schema.describeTabs() only lists classic apps, not lightning apps.

Answer (score 2):

Following code can be used for Lightning apps:

```
 UserAppInfo userAppInfo = [SELECT Id, AppDefinitionId FROM UserAppInfo WHERE UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
 AppDefinition appDefinition = [SELECT DurableId, Label FROM AppDefinition Where DurableId = :userAppInfo.AppDefinitionId LIMIT 1];
 system.debug( '***'+ appDefinition.Label );
```